# replacing and enclosed in spaces with &amp;

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

In javascript, I'm trying to replace the word 'and' with '&' with this script:

```
a.replace(/and/g, "&amp;");
```

But I'm having problems if the value of a has a word that includes the word 'and'

For example, the value of a is "Mandy and Adrian"

with my code, the a becomes this:

"M&y & Adrian"

How do I replace the 'and' word only on the one with spaces around it?

If I do this:

```
a.replace(/ and /g, "&amp;");
```

I get this:

"Mandy and Adrian"

How do i do "Mandy & Adrian" successfully with javascript? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use word breaks:

```
a.replace(/\band\b/g, "&amp;");
```

The `\b` matches the start or end of a word.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/aTTAppmL-MOtrWiD)